# How can I make a 2 ComboBox, the first one is a category and the other is a subcategory of the first?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table in a database with a 2 `column` which are `carbrand` and `carmodel`, I inserted this data in the table:

```
INSERT INTO cars ('carbrand', 'carmodel') 
           VALUES('Honda', 'City'), 
                 ('Honda', 'Civic'),
                 ('Honda', 'Jazz'),
                 ('Toyota', 'Corolla'),
                 ('Toyota', 'Altis');
```

I want my first ComboBox to contain the carbrand then populate the second ComboBox with it's corresponding carmodel and vice versa. Currently this is the snippet of the code that I have written so far.

```
private void PopulateCarBrandComboBox() {
    String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT carbrand FROM cars";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            String nme = rs.getString("carbrand");
            carbrandComboBox.addItem(nme);                
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}

private void PopulateCarModelComboBox() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carbrand = ?";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, (String)carbrandComboBox.getSelectedItem());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            String nme = rs.getString("carmodel");
            carmodeleComboBox.addItem(nme);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: And, where is the problem?

Comment: My carbrandComboBox and carmodelComboBox doesn't have anything inside.

Comment: Do the queries return any results?

Comment: stacktrace? do you have data in db?

Comment: @qqilihq
Oh yes, I forgot to mention that the carbrandComboBox contains 1 data which is 'Honda'.

Yes it is full of data.

Comment: I think you're better off loading the full table into a Map and then feed those combo boxes off it. Avoid hitting the database every now and then.